# SAPUI5 - how to format decimals on a calculated table field?

Tags: sapui5

This works like a charm in terms of calculating, but it generates a number with a ton of decimals. I'd like this limited to 2. (ie instead of 2.6929133858267718, i'd like 2.69)

I've seen some formatting options online, but all of these use a path attribute that doesn't seem to work on calculations. Any ideas?

The snippet of my view.xml looks like this:

```
<m:items>
<m:ColumnListItem type="Navigation" press=".onGoaliePress">
<m:cells>
<m:ObjectNumber
id="gaaCalc"
number="{= (${goalieData>shotsAgainst} - ${goalieData>saves}) / ${goalieData>minutes} * 60}"
emphasized="false"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Expression Binding](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0) supports function calls. So you could use Math.round()  here.
For more complex situations a [Formatter](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de) is more suitable than Expression Binding.